# Could not find or load main class when I add external libraries

Tags: java, compilation, cmd

Hey I got this problem when running a java program through my cmd.

I use to external libraries : lwjgl.jar and slick-util.jar

when I compile

```
javac -d bin -sourcepath src -cp ;lib/lwjgl.jar;lib/slick-util.jar src/*.java
```

everything works fine

but when I try to run it

```
java -cp bin .;lib/lwjgl.jar;lib/slick-util.jar; Game
```

I get this error

```
Error: could not find or load main class .;lib.lwjgl.jar;lib.slick-util.jar;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the space in the run command classpath with a classpath separator

```
java -cp bin;.;lib/lwjgl.jar;lib/slick-util.jar; Game
            ^
```

as an improvement to the run command you could use a classpath wilcards, for example

```
java -cp ".;bin;lib/*" Game
```

It is important to use quotes under Windows for this option

Comment: Okay I added the ";" so it's looks like yours above but now i get the following error

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl in java.library.path ...`

Comment: That's a different error where the the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` needs to be set for `lwjgl`. However that is for another post.The JVM is now finding the `Game` class.

Comment: So i opened a new post and the people at stackoverflow solved it [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17989345/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-no-lwjgl-in-java-libary-path-at-java-run)