# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl in java.libary.path at java run

Tags: java, path, cmd, lwjgl

I'm trying to run my java program with 2 external libraries ( lwjgl.jar and slick-util.jar )

compiling worked fine

but when i run with the following command:

```
java -cp bin;.;lib/lwjgl.jar;lib/slick-util.jar; Game
```

I get the following Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl in java.library.path
```

Comment: Did you do a search before you posted? See this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588799/when-i-run-the-jar-i-get-a-no-lwjgl-in-java-library-path-error)

Comment: You're not including the path to where the lwjgl binaries are in the launch parameters. `-Djava.library.path="path/to/lwjgl<exe/so>"`.

Comment: Yes, I've searched. But that isn't exactly my problem. I don't use any IDE and i'm trying to run it in the windows console.

At @BryanAbrams: SO i have to add `-Djava.library.path="path/to/lwjgl.jar"´ but where exactly in the command?

Comment: @Tomato There should be a DLL (or `.so`) that comes with `lwjgl` set the `java.library.path` to its location

Comment: @Reimeus @BryanAbrams Okay my current command is `java -cp bin;.;lib/lwjgl.jar;lib/slick-util.jar; -Djava.library.path="D:\dev\LWJGL\lwjgl-2.9.0\native\windows\lwjgl.dll" Game` Still same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Okay my current command is:

```
java -cp bin;.;lib/lwjgl.jar;lib/slick-util.jar; 
    -Djava.library.path="D:\dev\LWJGL\lwjgl-2.9.0\native\windows\lwjgl.dll"
```

Change that to:

```
java -cp bin;.;lib/lwjgl.jar;lib/slick-util.jar; 
    -Djava.library.path="D:\dev\LWJGL\lwjgl-2.9.0\native\windows"
```

The `-Djava.library.path` is a search path; i.e. a list of places to look for the `lwjgl.dll` file.

Comment: Oh my god, @Stephen C you just saved my world :p. My command is now `java -cp bin;.;lib/lwjgl.jar;lib/slick-util.jar; -Djava.library.path="D:\dev\LWJGL\lwjgl-2.9.0\native\windows" Game` and it works.

Comment: I'm not your god.  I refuse to take that responsibility :-).